# mysql out of space error

Tags: mysql, unix, diskspace, datadirectory

I am getting this error from mysql

ERROR 20 (HY000) at line 1: Disk is full writing './homo_sapiens_core_60_37e/dna_align_feature.MYD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... (Expect up to 60 secs delay for server to continue after freeing disk space)

I think this could be because i only have space on /local (df - h gives)

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/components-root
                       19G   18G     0 100% /
none                  1.4G  240K  1.4G   1% /dev
none                  1.4G  100K  1.4G   1% /dev/shm
none                  1.4G   80K  1.4G   1% /var/run
none                  1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /var/lock
none                  1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /lib/init/rw
none                   19G   18G     0 100% /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs
/dev/sdb1             241G   43G  186G  19% /local
/dev/sda1             228M   51M  166M  24% /boot
```

How do you specify where mysql writes its databases to? Perhaps there is no space where it is writing the database?

How do you configure where mysql writes its databases? perhaps there is no space where it is trying to write teh data?

I am a unix novice and don't know much mysql either so please be gentle in your answers!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have `/etc/my.cnf` then it may be helpful. If I understand correctly,, The data directory is specified either in startup options or it is defaulted from that file. You would want to edit `my.cnf` and choose a directory in `/local` and then manually transfer your existing data from wherever it was to your new place in `/local`. Make sure MySQL is not running during the transfer.

Answer (score 1):

In your `/etc/my.cnf`, under the heading `[mysqld]`, your [the data directory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir) is identified by `datadir`.

Also perhaos of interest, in case they were changed from their default, you should also check

- the location of your [temporary directory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir) `tmpdir`
- the [location](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) (`log-bin`) and [history length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days) (`expire-log-days`) of binary logs you're saving (if any)
- [the innodb directories](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_data_home_dir) (`innodb_data_file_path` and `innodb_data_home_dir`)
- the [location of your slow logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_slow_queries) with `slow-query-log-file` (the size of these logs will depend on how low your *slow* threshold is).

You can check all of these by doing a `SHOW VARIABLES` from the MySQL command line. Also note that MySQL only reads the values in the `/etc/my.cnf` upon startup, so changing the file while MySQL is running won't do anything.

Lastly, you might get more help/ideas at serverfault.